# перегрузка оператора преобразования типов С++

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачу: Реализовать класс var - «Универсальная переменная». Объекты экземпляры этого класса способны хранить в себе значения следующих типов: int, double, String(строка – уже готовый класс).
Не понятно как преобразовать строку в число и наоборот

Comment: Непонятно, зачем вам это нужно. В том плане, что вам нужно просто хранить флажок, какой именно тип хранится в объекта, а не придумывать, как превратить `"Hello, world!"` в число...

Comment: Я так понимаю, вам нужно хранить число, и присваивать или возвращать его либо как `double`, либо как `int`, либо как `string`?

Comment: да. например: 50 + "15" = 65. Здесь строка "15" преобразовывается в число

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
 
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
    string inp = "Hello";
 
    cout << "Input String: " << inp << endl;
 
    // Use std::stoi() to convert string to integer
    try {
        // Wrap up code in try-catch block if string is not validated
        int res = stoi(inp);
        cout << "Integer: " << res << endl;
    }
    catch(std::invalid_argument e) {
        cout << "Caught Invalid Argument Exception\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Код утащен [отсюда](https://arduinoplus.ru/preobrazovanie-stroki-string-v-czeloe-chislo-int-v-c/). Если вы копируете чужой код или тексты в ответ, вы обязаны указывать источник, иначе это считается плагиатом. Подробнее тут: [Users are calling me a plagiarist. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/353058)

Comment: Это неверно. В данном коде нет перегрузки оператора преобразования.